# Requesting assistance with modifying a .js script to include opening tabs in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

To start things off, I have basically no javascript experience and I am trying to modify a pre-existing `.js` file used in my office to quickly open up several web pages from one file.  It is really helpful in a quick start, and though it was written by a different person who is, unfortunately, no longer around to maintain the file, I have been able to keep it up to date with the changes that happen around here.

The downside is that the script exclusively opens the pages in IE, and there are a couple of links that I want to convert to opening in Chrome instead as they run much more efficiently there.  So far I haven't been able to find the right way to code it, nor the right sort of variables/definitions to use.  The original script is as follows (page addresses removed, of course, minus the last one to provide reference);

```
var navOpenInBackgroundTab = 0x1000;
var oIE = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
oIE.Navigate2("http://[address]", navOpenInBackgroundTab);
oIE.Navigate2("http://www.carfax.com/", navOpenInBackgroundTab);
oIE.Visible = true;
```

---

### this section edited to update on issue progress

The .js file being used is a stand alone file resting on the windows desktop and is not being run within or embedded as a part of any html environment, and calls on using Active X objects to function.  It has no user interaction other than your basic .exe style double click and it runs.  Thanks to your assistance and suggestions so far it has been established that Active X does not connect/utilise Chrome unless an additional plugin is downloaded ([ActiveXobject](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lgllffgicojgllpmdbemgglaponefajn)).  I have been unable to clarify if this plugin allows chrome to utilize activex within the environment (IE; a web authoring tool), or if it allows activex itself to call on chrome as a valid object. However it is nonviable as a solution due to admin restrictions in my situation.

My question is now one of alternative ways I can target a link to chrome, such as through old-fasioned html coding or a javascript version thereof that would let me call a link and set a target without using axtiveX.  Is this possible/does code exist that can be used within the same .js file without mucking things up?  (preferrably something that can be done in one or two lines.  I don't have the skill to be writing my own libraries. ... Also, I am lazy. ¬_¬)

Comment: You said that some links need to open in IE, even if you're starting in Chrome? Huh...unless I'm missing something, I think that would break Chrome's security model. From Chrome's POV, what you're doing is "Run arbitrary program name on hard disk, with given parameters", which it's not likely to allow for security reasons. You might be able to code an ActiveX object so this can at least work in Internet Explorer, but that would have to be a binary/registry patch applied to every workstation. Sorry, that's probably not a lot of help.

Comment: No worries.  I will see if I can clarify it for you.  My workplace uses several programs accessed remotely through web addresses, which can only be used through IE.  One of my co-workers wrote a stand alone .js script file so all we need to do is go into windows, double click like any windows .exe, and it fires up the stuff we need.  However some of the stuff we use (like mapping) is better done through google chrome, so I was hoping to change a couple (but not all) of the link calls in the file to open up in chrome instead of IE.

Comment: ActiveX is a common-architecture system Microsoft invented to have better cross-program communication. I think it was very useful for people writing script files meant to interact with Office products. However, a program has to specifically register itself and its interactions for an ActiveXObject script to be able to "see" it. Internet Explorer is in its mappings, but I'd be very surprised if Chrome added one for itself. That's why I don't think you could open things in Chrome. Maybe you could have those links just open in the same browser as you clicked from? (ie, using window.open)

Comment: it isn't opening from a browser but from a plain stand alone .js file sitting on the computer desktop. ...and i realized that last post probably wasn't very helpful, but the edit timer locked me, so i can't...err... clarify the clarification.  What I wanted to get across was that I want to continue to use the same .js but to define a new, additional variable that will target chrome instead of IE, to let me have my choice in where a new link will open.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on how the calls work though.  I was hoping that there would be a chrome entry in the mappings... if not then I suppose I am stuck with IE only.  Is there an alternate way to set up the new variable? ... maybe by path name instead of the mapping?

Comment: If the JS file is being run from the desktop you might have more options. I'm actually less familiar with Windows' built-in JavaScript execution environments. PS: If you have more information you can add to your question, it's okay to Edit it. (It's possible you need a certain reputation score)

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that you get the same result by calling `window.open("website url", "_blank")` multiple times, using Chrome.

It might give a warning that the page is trying to open other pages, but since it is from a "trusted source", you can disable this warning and it'll not annoy you anymore.

Comment: Hmm... I gave that a try however it returned an error;  'window' is undefined, under code 800a1391.  Also, it goes to default browser which is IE.  ... The complicator to all this is that I can't simply redefine the default to chrome because some of the links will only function within IE.  so the script needs to call to both IE and chrome.  (some links go to chrome, some to IE).  Is there a way to add a variable to the 'window.open' command to direct it to chrome?

Comment: I have found the problem already. My solution is not possible, unless it is triggered by an user interaction (user clicking on a button, for example).

Comment: In that case I'll label that tip a dead end for now.  Thanks for the try though, I do appreciate it!  (Also I didn't realize pressing 'enter' auto added the comment.  I tried to make a new paragraph and  I had to edit in the error.  Sorry about that.)